# CSS3: If input checked, get inputs data attribute as :before of "p" sibling

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to affect `:before` of sibling (`p`) with no JavaScript - just CSS, by triggering `input` (toggle `:checked`).

I'm wondering if that's even possible. I have this CSS code:

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
}

.parent input[data-label]:checked ~ p:before {
    content:attr(data-label);
}

/* if the first input selected then show different text in p:before -
   the first input equals to none checked */

.parent input:nth-child(1):checked ~ p:before {
    content:"Please select one option";
}
```

and this HTML code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="first" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="second" data-label="Second Option" />
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="third" data-label="Third Option" />
    <p></p>
</div>
```

What do you think - Is it possible to be done with css? if it is, how? if not, and JavaScript is the only solution - can it be done without jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately what you try won'nt work, it will look for the value of a data-label attribute from <p> only

Comment: @GCyrillus Javascript is the only way?

Comment: js is the only unless you prepare p to switch value extracted from different attributes

Answer (score 1):

content can only pickup attribute's value from its own container, you may set them like this :

```css
/* if the first input selected then show different text in p:before -
   the first input equals to none checked */

.parent input:nth-child(1):checked ~ p:before {
    content:"Please select one option";
}
.parent input[id="second"]:checked ~ p:before {
    content:attr(data-label2);
}
.parent input[id="third"]:checked ~ p:before {
    content:attr(data-label3);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="first" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="second" />
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="third"/>
    <p data-label2="Second Option"  data-label3="Third Option" ></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the sibings-selector you've already kinda given the answer:

```css
.parent {
    position:relative;
}

.parent input[data-label]:checked ~ p:before {
    content:attr(data-label);
}

/* if the first input selected then show different text in p:before -
   the first input equals to none checked */

.parent input:nth-child(1):checked ~ p:before {
    content:"Please select one option";
}
.parent #second:checked ~ p:before {
    content:"2nd option selected";
}

.parent #third:checked ~ p:before {
    content:"3rd option selected";
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="first" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="second" data-label="Second Option" />
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="third" data-label="Third Option" />
    <p></p>
</div>
```